# How to optimize this for mobile?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I used the bootstrap and jquery cdn to optimize my app on top of using meta. I fixed some of it the 3 bars at top is now responsive and it collapses or expands on click. Still however, cart icon and login button are hidden behind the product (in store) on mobile. (You will notice it if you long press on picture that two button are hidden behind it.) Any suggestions to fix this?

You can have a look at the website here:

https://market-shaurya.herokuapp.com

My base html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ecom</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" style="height:80px">
                    <a style="font-size:33px; color: #ffae00" class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'store' %}"><strong><strong>Ma₹ket</strong></strong></a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'store' %}">Items(Store) <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>

                      </ul>
                        {% block right_panel %}
                          <form class="form-inline mr-auto my-lg-0" method="get">
                          <!--<input class="form-control mr-sm-2" style="width:1000px; height:38px;" type="text" placeholder="Search for items" aria-label="Search">-->
                            {{myFilter.form}}
                          <button class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-rounded btn-sm ml-2 my-0" style="width:80px; height:38px" type="submit">Search</button>
                          </form>
                        {% endblock %}
                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                          <div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                            <span class="hello-msg"><strong></strong>Hello, {{ request.user }}</strong></span>
                            <a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="btn btn-danger">Logout</a>
                            <a href="{% url 'cart' %}">
                            <img  id="cart-icon" src="{% static 'images/cart.png' %}">
                                </a>
                                <p id="cart-total">{{cartItems}}</p>
                          </div>

                        {% else %}
                          {% block left_panel %}
                            <div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                                <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="btn btn-success">Login</a>
                                <a href="{% url 'cart' %}">
                                  <img  id="cart-icon" src="{% static 'images/cart.png' %}">
                                </a>
                                <p id="cart-total">{{cartItems}}</p>
                            </div>
                          {% endblock %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>

                  </nav>

        <hr>
        <div class="container">
            <br>
            {% block content %}

            {% endblock content %}
        </div>


    </body>

      <!-- jQuery !-->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
      <!-- jQuery UI !-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/cart.js' %}"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Your cart and login buttons are inside the navbar, which collapses on mobile. Is that what you want? You may also want to consider setting the `z-index` of the cart and login buttons so they appear in front of the images.

Comment: Also, should I not have z index of navbar greater than that of images below instead since all these buttons are part of navbar itself?

Comment: Yes, I want those two buttons in the navbar itself. Will try the z-index setting and let you know. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: No need to change the `z-index` of items inside the navbar if the navbar itself has a higher `z-index` than the images. FYI, Bootstrap already provides classes for [sticky top navbars](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/navbar-top-fixed/).

Comment: Implemented the change now navbar contents show above the pictures. Can you tell me how to make background solid when navbar expands? Currently after change the cart button overlaps the picture but its like the background is transparent. I would prefer something like this. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/navbar-top-fixed/

Comment: I removed the height attribute now its fine.